Setting up a Cypress test suite to test a Twilio Flex application
I have been trying to setup an automated integration test for our Flex applicaiton.  We have a fairly complicated application and want to automate more tests before each release and if we could automate some of our call flows that would help a lot.
I have setup our flex application in the Cypress test suite.  I can login.  I can use the low level API calls to even have Cypress make an incoming call.
What I am having trouble with is that the logged in agent while in the Cypress test browser, does not answer the call.  It starts to popup inbound call information, but does not answer.  Twilio generates a bunch of logs for the incoming call while trying to comlete the conference to the agent, but those calls all report as busy.
I have already turned off initialDeviceCheck due to the fact that Cypress test browser is faking the audio.  I do suspect this is still part of the problem, but have not found anything to help me get past this current point.
Any help or anyone that has successfully done this type of automation would be greatly appreciated as to how they did it.  Most of the online tutorials are actually fairly spartan and stick to things like send SMS messages.
